# Reading file data from Multiple SFTP servers using JSch

Tags: java, ssh, sftp, jsch

Could any one provide info on, how to connect to multiple SFTP servers with Java JSch  client?.

I have around Four remote SFTP servers containing files, and expectation is read the files from all the Four SFTP servers

does Java JSch client library has support for opening multiple SFTP connection to multiple remote SFTP servers ?.
Ex: For the Four remote SFTP servers Four connection, once connection per SFTP server.

Comment: Did you try to download a file from one server? If yes, where in that code do you have problems extending it to multiple servers? If not, I would suggest that you try this, the JSch homepage has even an [example](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/ScpFrom.java.html) how to download a file with scp.

Answer (score 0):

Referencing [JSch - Examples - Sftp.java](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Sftp.java.html) and the [ChannelSftp JavaDoc](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html)

```java
JSch jsch=new JSch();

// Create a session to your first SFTP server
Session session1 = jsch.getSession("username", "hostname1.com", 22);
session1.connect();
// Open an SFTP channel and connect
ChannelSftp sftpChannel1 = (ChannelSftp) session1.openChannel("sftp");
sftpChannel1 .connect();
// Run SFTP commands
sftpChannel1.get("/path/to/file");

// Create a session to your second SFTP server
Session session2 = jsch.getSession("username", "hostname2.com", 22);
session2.connect();
// Open an SFTP channel and connect
ChannelSftp sftpChannel2 = (ChannelSftp) session2.openChannel("sftp");
sftpChannel2.connect();
// Run SFTP commands
sftpChannel2.get("/path/to/file");

// Repeat as many times as needed
```